# Can I use my own voice recognition API for Arabic language in Alexa skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I already have a voice recognition API for Arabic language but Alexa does not support Arabic language so can I use my API?

Answer (score 1):

No, because at the moment you have to define all your intents and sample utterances in Alexa interaction model (https://developer.amazon.com ). At the moment it supports only English-US, English-UK, and German. As you cannot configure the Arabic Language in that you cannot interact with Alexa in Arabic. Maybe in feature release, Amazon will come up with more language support.